# mysql select matching results

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find the leagues (lid) where two users are apart of.

Here are my tables:

Table leagues:

```
*id*    lname
--------------
 1      Hard C
 3      Fun
 5      Crazy
```

Table match:

```
*userid*   *lid* 
-----------------
   1         1
   4         5
   1         3
   2         1
   4         1
   4         3
```

*Are primary keys

`match.lid` is foreign key to `leagues.id` (a user cannot not be part of the same league twice)

Here's what I have so far (a start):

```
SELECT t1.lid, t2.lname 
FROM match t1
JOIN leagues t2 on t1.lid = t2.id
```

So far I managed to join the two tables and get the names. My ultimate goal is to show the `lid`'s where two users are part of the same league, say `userid` 1 and 4.

`userid` 1 is a member of `lid` 1 and 3

`userid` 4 is a member of `lid` 5, 1, and 3

Both users meet in league(`lid`) 1 and 3

So I need a query that shows only the league where both users meet. Like this:

```
lid    lname
--------------
 1      Hard C
 3      Fun
```

Since `userid` 1 and 4 meet in league 1 and 3, the results should show that. I can run two queries for each user and check which leagues both users meet via php, but I think it's more efficient to run one query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT m1.lid, l.lname FROM 
`match` m1, `match` m2, leagues l
WHERE m1.lid = m2.lid AND m1.lid = l.id 
  AND m1.userid = 1 
  AND m2.userid = 4
```

Comment: Simple and fast `Query took 0.0004 sec`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways. The most straightforward is:

```
SELECT id AS lid,
       lname
  FROM leagues
 WHERE id IN
        ( SELECT lid
            FROM match
           WHERE userid = 1
        )
 AND id IN
        ( SELECT lid
            FROM match
           WHERE userid = 4
        )
;
```

Another way, which is a bit less direct, but *may* perform better — you can try it and see — is to use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT id AS lid,
       lname
  FROM leagues
  JOIN match AS match1
    ON match1.lid = leagues.id
   AND match1.userid = 1
  JOIN match AS match2
    ON match2.lid = leagues.id
   AND match2.userid = 4
;
```